# Java 1.6 -> 1.8, same erasure compile error

Tags: java, polymorphism, erasure

I'm porting my Java app from 1.6 to 1.8 and the compiler is unhappy with the methods `getAbstractTransactionCriteria()` in the following code:

```
public abstract class AbstractTransaction ...
public class TemplateTransaction extends AbstractTransaction ...
public class Transaction extends AbstractTransaction ...

abstract class AbstractTransactionCriteria {...}
class TransactionCriteria extends AbstractTransactionCriteria {...}
class TemplateCriteria extends AbstractTransactionCriteria {...}

TransactionCriteria getAbstractTransactionCriteria(Class<Transaction> c) {...}
TemplateCriteria    getAbstractTransactionCriteria(Class<TemplateTransaction> c) {...}
```

The compiler tells me the two methods have the same erasure, which I can accept because I've seen elsewhere that the things inside the angle brackets get replaced by `Object` by the compiler.

The arguments `c` are only there to achieve the polymorphism (they're not used in the method bodies) and this used to work perfectly in Java 1.6.

What should I do to achieve the same result in 1.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are at liberty to change the function prototypes, and the arguments are not used except to determine the return type, then would the following work for you?

```
TransactionCriteria getAbstractTransactionCriteria(Transaction c) {...}
TemplateCriteria    getAbstractTransactionCriteria(TemplateTransaction c) {...}
```

Alternatively, you could use different function names and have them take no arguments.  For example

```
TransactionCriteria getAbstractTransactionCriteria() {...}
TemplateCriteria    getAbstractTemplateCriteria() {...}
```

Comment: So, pass in a dummy Transaction/TemplateTransaction?  Yes, I could do that.  It does seem a little clumsy though.  Is there no way to do what I used to do?

Comment: However, what do I do with abstract classes?  Is there really no way to do what I used to do?  I really don't want to have to make up spuriously different names just to get around the damn compiler.  Is such polymorphism no longer allowed?

Comment: @skiaddict1 it suprisses me even that this approuch is allowed in java 1.6 since from my understanding there is no way to achieve polymorphism based on genericType arguments. A general workaround which I use a lot when dealing with the same problem is using generics as arguments (like in my answer) I hope it helps you further, otherwise you'll need to go for either an additional argument (for example an Integer type) for each polymorphid method. Or use a static place holder instance for each method instead of the classType.

Comment: @n247s I like your approach better than having to pass in, e.g. `new Foo()`.  But what does "a static place holder instance" mean, please? :-)

Comment: @skiaddict1  There is no need for new Foo().  Create public static (final) instances of the classes in the Abstract class.  So you method call might look something like getAbstractTransactionCriteria(AbstractTransation.TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION).     You say that you don't want to make up spurious different names.  YOu have to methods that require no arguments and have different return types.  Why wouldn't they have separate names?  For example.  To me, getStudent() and getTeacher() makes more sense than get(flag_for_student) and get(flag_for_teacher).

Comment: @Teto Thank you for your help, but we're going to have to agree to disagree. I can see the point you're making, but to me they both return `AbstractTransactionCriteria`, that's why I want them to be polymorphic. This is a pattern I use extensively and I can't see why Java has now disallowed it.  Also, I can't use the public static instance idea since sometimes the Class object passed in is something like `java.sql.Date`.  There simply has to be a way to achieve polymorphism in this new Java!

Comment: @Teto OK, I surrender.  I've ended up using a combination of your approaches.  Some of the methods are renamed and some are combined into one longer method which uses instanceof to check for the exact class passed in.  I must say I don't like having to do it, but if that's necessary then so be it....    Thanks again both of you for your help.

Comment: @n247s OK, I surrender. I've ended up using a combination of your approaches. Some of the methods are renamed and some are combined into one longer method which uses instanceof to check for the exact class passed in. I must say I don't like having to do it, but if that's necessary then so be it.... Thanks again both of you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using generics for this? Like something like this:

```
 public <T extends AbstractTransactionCriteria> T getAbstractTransactionCriteria(Class<T> c) {}
 // or
 public <T extends AbstractTransactionCriteria> T getAbstractTransactionCriteria(T t) {}
```

This way you only need one method. Now Im aware that both methods may be completly different (content wise). Though even than you can simply check the passed in argument type, and perform the actions accordingly.

**Edit:**
I mentioned a static placeHolder to support polymorphism.
Basically if you see both approuches above, one asks a Class object while the other asks for an instance (usually less ideal since you call this method to create an instance, not to pass in one).

If you don't want to use genericTypes as described above, you can also choose to do something like this:

```
 abstract class AbstractTransactionCriteria {...}

 // SubClass layout
 class TransactionCriteria extends AbstractTransactionCriteria {
     // dummy instance doing nothing.
     public static final TransactionCriteria type = new TransactionCriteria();
 }

 class TemplateCriteria extends AbstractTransactionCriteria {
     // dummy instance doing nothing.
     public static final TemplateCriteria type = new TemplateCriteria ();
 }



 // method layout
 TransactionCriteria getAbstractTransactionCriteria(TransactionCriteria t)
 {...}

 TemplateCriteria getAbstractTransactionCriteria(TemplateCriteria  t)
 {...}


 // Call methods
 TransactionCriteria transaction = getAbstractTransactionCriteria(TransactionCriteria.type);
 TemplateCriteria transaction = getAbstractTransactionCriteria(TemplateCriteria.type);
```

As you can see, this way it is kinda possible to use your 'old' layout. Though if this is the only way, I would defenitly advise you to redesign you current pattern since its defenitly not ideal.
(as mentioned earlier you might want to consider using different names for every method, as they kinda return different results than their method name suggests in this case)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, thanks for putting the time into showing me.  Unfortunately that's not going to work because sometimes this pattern uses things like `java.sql.Date` :-(  As mentioned above, I disagree that I should be using different names per method.  They both return `AbstractTransactionCriteria`, it makes perfect sense to call them that.  In other places I do the same thing with various forms of dates, why have `getDatejavasqlDate(...)` and `getDateMyCriteriaDate(...)`?  Yuck!  I'm going to have to research polymorphism in this new Java.  I'll report back. Thanks again.

Comment: @skiaddict1 As argument against your approuch not having different method names I would say that there is no need for overflowing methods, since you know the difference before calling (e.g. there is no genericType involved in any method or class). More specifically, you (have to) pass in the type, so why not using different names to solve this problem the easy (clean) way? Although it might look cleaner at a first glance, to achieve this in java becomes messy and over complicated real quick.

Comment: apologies for not marking your answer as correct, I would have liked to mark both but wasn't allowed to!  I upvoted it as all I could do...   Thanks again for your help.